# Strapi : populate result from a relation collection

Tags: mongodb, strapi

I'm using strapi 3.4.4 with mongodb.
I've got a location collection with a reservation linked collection (a location can have many reservations).

Location Model

- text field : title of the location

Reservations Model

- linked collection : has one author

My goal is to populate the author name when I made a get request to /location
But right now, my request is :

```
{
"reservations": [
   {
   "_id": "60be41626a15ab675c91f417",    
   "author": "60be3d40ea289028ccbd4d5a",
   "id": "60be41626a15ab675c91f417"
   }
],
"_id": "60be40a26a15ab675c91f414",
"title": "New York Plaza",
},
```

As you can see, the author is an id, so I try to edit location/controllers/location.js to

```
const { sanitizeEntity } = require('strapi-utils');

module.exports = {
  /**
   * Retrieve records.
   *
   * @return {Array}
   */

  async find(ctx) {
    let entities;
    if (ctx.query._q) {
      entities = await strapi.services.location.search(ctx.query);
    } else {
      entities = await strapi.services.location.find(ctx.query, ['reservations', 'reservations.author']);
    }

    return entities.map(entity => sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.location }));
  },
};
```

I followed this guide : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBNjCgUokLk&list=PL7Q0DQYATmvhlHxHqfKHsr-zFls2mIVTi&index=27

Answer (score 1):

After further research, it seems that the syntax ['reservations', 'reservations.author'] doesn't work to populate with mongodb.

```
await strapi.services.post.find(ctx.query, {path:'reservations', populate:{path:'author'}});
```

works

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the API key you're using "Full access" for what ever reason, "Read only" won't return relations.

On top of that you will still need to use the query parameter `populate`.

```
http://localhost:1337/api/locations?populate=*
```